# Accessors' design

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

Given I have

```
class IChunk
{
  public:
    const char* getRawData() = 0;
    ...
};

class Chunk
{
  public:
    const char* getRawData();
    ...

  private:
    char* data;
};

class IDatabase
{
  public:
    IChunk* getChunk( int index ) = 0;
    ...
};

class Database : public IDatabase
{
  public:
    IChunk* getChunk( int index );
    ...

  private:
    std::vector< Chunk > m_chunks;
};
```

I would like to interpret the raw data returned by `getRawData()` differently with a number of accessors. The accessors use both `IChunk` and `IDatabase` interfaces.

1. What will be the best placement for accessor creation?
   Would it be correct to extend `IDatabase` interface with a creation function like this:

   ```
   IAccessor*  a  = database->createAccessor( ACC_ID_1, index );
   IAccessor1* a1 = dynamic_cast< IAccessor1* >a;
   IAccessor*  a  = database->createAccessor( ACC_ID_2, index );
   IAccessor1* a2 = dynamic_cast< IAccessor2* >a;
   ```

   where `index` is chunk's index and `ACC_ID_x` is an accessor interface ID.
2. The dynamic cast will be required in this case, which might be not safe and the design is not very good. Can I improve it?
3. Which design pattern should I look at to implement accessors' factory? My intention is to permit adding accessors (and corresponding accessor ID) dynamically.
4. Would it be OK to implement accessor creation by something like this:

   ```
   IAccessor3* a3;
   database->createAccessor( ACC_ID_3, index, (void**)&a3 );
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not pass the database object and chunk index as constructor parameters to the accessors?

```
class IAccessor
{
protected:
  IAccessor (IDatabase *database, int index) : m_database (database), m_index (index) {}
  IDatabase *m_database;
  int m_index;
};

class Accessor1 : public IAccessor
{
public:
  Accessor1 (IDatabase *database, int index) : IAccessor (database, index) {}
};
```

and then:

```
Accessor1 a1 (database, index);
some_value = a1.SomeFunction ();
```

Comment: The solution is supposed to be a library implementation. Some accessors will be implemented inside this library. I'd like the library users could extend the functionality and follow the same mechanism that library uses by itself. The library is capable to return pointers to interfaces, not class instances.

Comment: @Serge: This doesn't prevent a library implementation. The library can provide several classes derived from IAccessor for general use and users can derive their own classes from IAccessor for specific needs. You could add accessors to the actual data into the IAccessor base class if you don't want custom IAccessors to have to handle IDatabase and IChunk objects.